# What statistic analysis should i use?

Tags: anova, t-test, biostatistics

I need to analyze this data. Tried with anova and independent t-test but i have no results. with t-test says t cannot be computed because standard deviation of both groups is zero, in anova says that needs at least 3 groups and i have 2. I need to find differences between this two groups, which analysis should i use?

Group 1 Enzyme activity (3876,3876,3875)
Group 2 Enzyme activity (4016, 4016, 4016)

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what "no results" might mean and--more importantly--what you are trying to accomplish with your analysis.  Otherwise, your question is kind of like asking "I have this rubber ball.  What should I do with it?"

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If the standard deviation of both groups is 0 then you have a typo in the first group.

When you have identical values, nothing like a t-test will work, because the standard deviation is in the denominator of the formula.

You could try a permutation test.

Comment: You can predict the result of a permutation test in this case without doing it, so why recommend going to the effort?